# Could Djinni record contain optional interface field

Tags: c++, objective-c, dropbox, djinni

Is this code valid in Djinni, and `some_record` can be generated for objective c?

```
some_service = interface +c 
{
    do_some_action(): bool;
}

some_record = record 
{
    service: optional< some_service >;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just try to run the djinni stuff and see if it accepts your snippet?

Comment: @skypjack Unfortunately, can't check it for objective c code generation.

Comment: Why not?  Even if you can't build the ObjC code because you're on Linux or something, you can still generate it, and Djinni won't generally let you generate invalid code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems simple and valid to me (though without trying it I'm not confident there's not a gotcha case I'm missing.

Note that optional interfaces are pretty meaningless in Djinni unless you're also using non-nullable pointer support (see the cpp-nn-* arguments).  Those depend on using a non-nullable template in C++ such as [nn<>](https://github.com/dropbox/nn)  Without that, interfaces are all nullable by default anyway.  With nn enabled, interfaces are non-nullable by default, and optional ends up as the nullable version.

Comment: Even though it actually seems valid it doesn't compile on mac os. Thank you for notice about meaningless optional interfaces.

Comment: Given optional interfaces aren't useful without nn<> it's quite possible it's a case we haven't tested and thus broke at some point.  You're welcome to submit an issue on GitHub with a test case which demos it, or even better a PR to fix it, if you think you still want to use this particular feature.